# Error Compiling pidgin on windows

Tags: compilation, pidgin, libpurple

Good day, I have been trying to compile pidgin on Windows 8 for some time now. I have been able to download all necessary files and put them in the correct folders, but when I attempt to use

```
$ make -f Makefile.mingw install
```

I get the following:

```
$ make -f Makefile.mingw install
make -C ../pidgin -f Makefile.mingw pidgin.dll
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/PidginBuild/pidgin-2.10.11/pidgin'
make -C ../libpurple -f Makefile.mingw libpurple.dll
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/PidginBuild/pidgin-2.10.11/libpurple'
gcc.exe -O2 -Wall -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wstack-protector -fwrapv -fno-strict-overflow -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat-security -fstack-protector-all --param ssp-buffer-size=1 -pipe -mms-bitfields -g -DHAVE_CYRUS_SASL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -I../libpurple -I../libpurple/win32 -I.. -I../../win32-dev/gtk_2_0-2.14/include -I../../win32-dev/gtk_2_0-2.14/include/glib-2.0 -I../../win32-dev/gtk_2_0-2.14/lib/glib-2.0/include -I../../win32-dev/libxml2-2.9.0/include/libxml2 -o account.o -c account.c
In file included from account.c:26:0:
internal.h:128:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
../libpurple/win32/rules.mak:4: recipe for target 'account.o' failed
make[2]: *** [account.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/PidginBuild/pidgin-2.10.11/libpurple'
../libpurple/win32/targets.mak:31: recipe for target '../libpurple/libpurple.dll.a' failed
make[1]: *** [../libpurple/libpurple.dll.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/PidginBuild/pidgin-2.10.11/pidgin'
../libpurple/win32/targets.mak:37: recipe for target '../pidgin/pidgin.dll.a' failed
make: *** [../pidgin/pidgin.dll.a] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this? I've tried performing searches but I can't find anything.

Comment: Is the `make` you're using from MinGW or from CygWin?

Comment: This helped. I have just installed more packages for MinGw, but i am using CygWin, the extra packages I have added in MinGW have solved the problem. Thanks. Now it says:   

cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wstack-protector"
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-missing-field-initializer                                     s"
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-strict-overflow"
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fstack-protector-all"
cc1.exe: error: invalid parameter `ssp-buffer-size'

Answer (score 0):

You've apparently been at this for several days:

- [Error Compiling pidgin on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627448/error-compiling-pidgin-on-windows)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667459/trouble-compiling-pidgin-on-windows
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695459/microsoft-manifest-tool-must-be-included-in-your-path
- [cygwin: cannot determine mount points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820112/cygwin-cannot-determine-mount-points)

Q: Have you got it working yet?

If not, please look here:

- https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/BuildingWinPidgin
- https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/BuildingWinPidgin/3.0.0