# cygwin: cannot determine mount points

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin

I have been trying to run a .bat file on windows. I'm attempting to build Nss, but when I run the .bat file I receive the following:

```
sh ../../build/cygwin-wrapper cl -Fonow.obj -c      -W3 -nologo -GF -Gy -MD -O2
  -UDEBUG -U_DEBUG -UWINNT -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_
VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -
DNDEBUG=1 -DXP_PC=1 -DWIN32=1 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARN
INGS=1 -DWIN95=1 -D_PR_GLOBAL_THREADS_ONLY=1 -D_AMD64_=1 -DFORCE_PR_LOG   "/c/Pi
dginBuild/win32/nss/nspr/WIN954.0_OPT.OBJ/config/../../config/now.c"
/usr/bin/mount: /etc/fstab.conf: configuration file not found
Can't find file Cannot determine cygwin mount points. Exiting
make[2]: *** [now.obj] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/PidginBuild/win32/nss/nspr/WIN954.0_OPT.OBJ/confi
g'
make[1]: *** [export] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/PidginBuild/win32/nss/nspr/WIN954.0_OPT.OBJ'
make: *** [build_nspr] Error 2
***
*** Build failed
***

C:\PidginBuild\win32\nss\nss>
```

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe your script or Makefile simply assumes a Unix environment.

SUGGESTION: try adding a Cygwin mount point and re-running the build:

- http://cygwin-lite.sourceforge.net/html/mount.html